# Struct fields should be all of same trait, but not neceesarily same type

Tags: struct, types, rust, traits

I am trying to implement the following trait and struct:

```rs
pub trait Funct {
    fn arity(&self) -> u32;
}

#[derive(Debug, Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct FunctionLiteral<T: Funct> {
    pub function: T,
    pub args: Vec< FunctionLiteral<T> >
}

pub enum Foo {
    Foo
}

impl Funct for Foo {
    fn arity(&self) -> u32 {0}
}

pub enum Bar {
    Bar
}

impl Funct for Bar {
    fn arity(&self) -> u32 {0}
}

fn main() {
    let baz = FunctionLiteral{
        function: Foo::Foo,
        args: vec![FunctionLiteral{
            function: Bar::Bar, 
            args: vec![]
        }]
    };
}
```

I can set it up the way I have for the generic type *T* to be of trait `Funct`, but I don't necessarily want `T` to be of the same type.

Here, compiling the code gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> foo.rs:31:23
   |
31 |             function: Bar::Bar, 
   |                       ^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Foo`, found enum `Bar`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is it possible to set up `FunctionLiteral` such that I can have different types for `function` and the items of `args`, while forcing both of them to be of type `Funct`?

Comment: Yes, you should `Box` them

Comment: `Box<dyn Funct>` in particular. Then `FunctionLiteral` doesn't even need to be generic. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The problem

When you do:

```
Structure<T: Trait>{
    inner: T,
    many: Vec<T>
}
```

You are telling the compiler to create a specialized instance for each different `T`. So if you have `Foo` and `Bar` both implementing `Trait`, then the compiler will generate two different representations, with two different sizes:

```rust
struct Foo(u8);
impl Trait for Foo{
    // impl goes here
}

struct Bar(u64);
impl Trait for Bar{
    // impl goes here
}
```

Then the compiler will generate something like:

```
Structure<Foo>{
    inner: Foo,
    many: Vec<Foo>
}

// and 
Structure<Bar>{  
    inner: Bar, 
    many: Vec<Bar>
}
```

Obviously you cannot put `Foo` instances into `Bar` as they are different types and have different sizes.

##### The solution

You need to `Box<>` your `Funct` types in order to make them the same size (i.e. pointer sized). By putting them behind a (smart) pointer you are essentially erasing their types:

```rust
    let a: Box<dyn Trait> = Box::new(Foo(0));
    let b: Box<dyn Trait> = Box::new(Bar(0));
```

Now both `a` and `b` have the same size (the size of a pointer) and have the same type - `Box<dyn Trait>`. So now you can do:

```rust
struct Structure{ // no longer generic!
    inner: Box<dyn Trait>, // can hold any `Box<dyn Trait>`
    many: Vec<Box<dyn Trait>> // can hold any `Box<dyn Trait>`
}
```

The downside of this approach is that it requires heap allocation and that it looses the exact type of `a` and `b`. Youno longer know if `a` is `Foo` or `Bar` or something else.

Instead of `Box` you can use any other smart pointer, such as `Rc` or `Arc` if you need its functionality.

##### Another option

Another option is to make `Foo` and `Bar` the same size and type. This can be done by wrapping them in an `enum`:

```rust
enum Holder{
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar),  // any other types go here in their own variants
}
```

Then your structure will look like:

```rust
struct Structure{ // no longer generic!
    inner: Holder, // can hold any Holder variant`
    many: Vec<Holder> // can hold any Holder variant`
}
```

The downside is that you have to either implement a delegation like:

```rust
impl Trait for Holder{
    fn some_method(&self){
        match self{
            Holder::Foo(foo) => foo.some_method(),
            Holder::Bar(bar) => bar.some_method(),
        }
    }
}
```

Or `match` everywhere you want to use the object. Also now your `Holder` enum will be the size of `max(sizeof(Foo), sizeof(Bar))`

On the plus side:

- you still know the actual type - it's not erased
- no heap allocation